# three tables in the same window, iPad

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, uitableview, uikit, uiviewcontroller

HI, I'm developing an app, in landscape mode,
I need to show 3 tables in the same window,
how to achieve this?
as my view controller, I have for one table>

```
@interface ChoiceViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{ 
    NSMutableArray *array;
}
```

but how to connect in the xib the new tables? how to call the other delegate, datasources, 
Uitableview for creating the new tables?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add IBOutlets in your view controller's interface:

```
@interface ChoiceViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
    UITableView *table1;
    UITableView *table2;
    UITableView *table3;
    NSMutableArray *array;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITableView *table1;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITableView *table2;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITableView *table3;
@end
```

Connect the outlets to the view controller in Interface Builder, optionally connect delegate/dataSource outlets of the table views back to the view controller. Then add the following to the implementation.

```
@implementation ChoiceViewController

@synthesize table1, table2, table3;

- (void) dealloc
{
    self.table1 = nil;
    self.table2 = nil;
    self.table3 = nil;
    // Most likely, [array release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

In your UITableViewDelegate/UITableViewDataSource methods test which table view asks for data and return the appropriate data.

Alternatively, you can set up multiple data sources, each responsible for one table view, but that depends on the design of your app.

Comment: hi, thank you, I tried this method, but got some errors, is this method fine to put different data in each table? tnx

Comment: Yes. If the view controller has logical access to the data to be displayed in the tables, it makes sense. Otherwise it may be better to have different data sources/delegates. What kind of errors do you see?